# Monotouch Custom UIView

Tags: ios, graphics, uiview, xamarin.ios

I want to create my own custom UIView because all the screens on the application will have a programmatically created background.

The question is, where should I override the drawRect method?

On the one side, it makes sense to have it **on the IB side**, since then I can assign the new created class UICustomView directly **in the Identity Inspector**.

On the other side, I'm newbie **in Monotouch, but seems all the logic should be on the c#.**

I tried to do it in both :) but nothing seems to work

Can you point me to some tutorial or give me some advise on which is the best method on overriding the UIVIew class in Monotouch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution right here:

http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/monotouch/2009-September/000599.html

Here is an example code:

```
using System;
using MonoTouch.CoreGraphics;
using System.Drawing;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace LongoMatch
{
    public partial class UICustomView : UIView
    {
        public UICustomView(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
        }

        public override void Draw (RectangleF rect)
        {
            MonoTouch.CoreGraphics.CGContext context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();

            context.SetLineWidth(8.0f);
            context.SetStrokeColor(new CGColor(0f, 0f, 0f));
            context.MoveTo(10,10);

            context.AddLines(new PointF[] { new PointF(60, 60), new PointF(100, 100) });

            context.StrokePath();

            SetNeedsDisplay();
        }


    }
}
```